# No option to create sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm in the Brackeys game jam 6 right now. I started a new URP project, changed the project settings to 2D (I'm making a 2D game but I needed the post-processing effects). Then when I was about to create a new 2D square, I don't see any option to do so. I tried opening another unity project I've been working on for a couple of months now, it uses the same version and the option to make 2D objects are there but not in this project.

[image: Screenshot of my unity page not showing 2D section]

I'm not in much hurry in the game as I'm also busy with online school but an quick answer would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a problem with your Project setup. install this PackageManager/2D Sprite

At the unity task bar (top). Go to Windows -> Package Manager --> 2D Sprite